# Error: Can't bind to 'ngForIn' . Angular 4+

Tags: angular, angular-template, angular4-forms

this question has already been said but unfortunately no answer worked for me.

Here is my problem (angular 5):

```
<option 
    *ngFor="let country in countries" 
    [value]="country.id" >
       {{'page.choose_country' | translate}} *
</option>
```

I have a simple code but it still shows me this error:

> Can't bind to 'ngForIn' since it isn't a known property of 'option'.

It does not accept *ngFor in select (I tested in input same result)

I've found several answers like `commModule` and `bowersModule` that need to be imported into the module or put b..... I tried to find solutions here, but nothing works.

I hope you've understood me a little bit, despite my scary English.
Thank you for your response

Answer (score 40, accepted):

It needs to be `of` instead of `in`

```
*ngFor="let country of countries"
```

Answer (score 6):

Change

```
*ngFor="let country in countries"
```

to

```
*ngFor="let country of countries"
```

There is no such thing `ngForIn` introduced from Angular side : **[Ref Link](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf)**